# How to prove that the trace of a density matrix is $1$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, mathematics, density-matrix, linear-algebra

[Equation 2](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599d/06wi/lecturenotes13.pdf) gives the following proof:

$$
\text{Tr}[\rho] = \sum_x \langle x\vert \rho\vert x\rangle = \sum_x \langle x\vert  
\sum_i p_i\vert \psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i\vert\vert x\rangle = \sum_i p_i\sum_x \vert \langle \psi_i\vert x\rangle \vert^2 = \sum_i p_i = 1.
$$

I wonder how they got from $\sum_x \langle x\vert  
\sum_i p_i\vert \psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i\vert\vert x\rangle$ to $\sum_i p_i\sum_x \vert \langle \psi_i\vert x\rangle \vert^2$. When I did the math, I got $\sum_x \sum_i p_i \langle x\vert \vert \psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i\vert \vert x\rangle$. Is it correct?

Comment: Three facts: 1. Addition can be done in any order. 2. Inner product is conjugate symmetric. 3. Product of any complex number with its conjugate equals the square of its absolute value.

Comment: @AdamZalcman thank you for the note. I am still not sure if my approach is correct. Do the step I have stopped at correct?

Comment: Yes, your intermediate step is correct, though people generally write a single | rather than two ||.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder how they got from $\sum_x \langle x\vert  
> \sum_i p_i\vert \psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i\vert\vert x\rangle$ to $\sum_i p_i\sum_x \vert \langle \psi_i\vert x\rangle \vert^2$.

> When I did the math, I got $\sum_x \sum_i p_i \langle x\vert \vert \psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i\vert \vert x\rangle$. Is it correct?

Yes. The meanings of the following three things are all the same:
$$
\langle x||\psi_i\rangle \equiv \langle x|\psi_i\rangle \equiv \psi_i(x)
$$

Similarly:
$$
\langle \psi_i||x\rangle \equiv \langle \psi_i|x\rangle = \langle x|\psi_i\rangle^* = \psi_i(x)^*
$$

So you can re-write:
$$
\langle x||\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i||x\rangle
= \langle x|\psi_i\rangle\langle x|\psi_i\rangle^*
\equiv |\langle x|\psi_i\rangle|^2\;,
$$
by definition of the absolute square:
$$
|z|^2 = z z^*
$$